# Extract 'href' from tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags, href

I have the following tags in html and I would like to extract only the href content ie Quatermass_2_Vintage_Movie_Poster-61-10782 and Hard Day's Night

```
<span class="small">
                                Ref.No:10782<br/>
<a href="Quatermass_2_Vintage_Movie_Poster-61-10782" title="Click for more details and a larger picture of Quatermass 2">
                                Click for more details and a larger picture of <b>Quatermass 2</b>
</a>
</span>, <span class="small">
                                Ref.No:10781<br/>
<a href="Hard_Day__039_s_Night_Vintage_Movie_Poster-61-10781" title="Click for more details and a larger picture of Hard Day's Night">
                                Click for more details and a larger picture of <b>Hard Day's Night</b>
</a>
</span>
```

The following python code enables me to find the entire tags only

```
html = ['table2.html']

with open("table2.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()


soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")

for name in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "small"}):
    print(name)
```

However unable to select href only. I have tried

```
for name in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "small"}.get(href)):
    print(name)
```

I have also tried putting the href reference in the print statment

```
for name in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "small"}:
    print(name.get('href'))
```

Could anyone kindly help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting the `span` tag you need to find the `a` tag and then grab the `href` attribute.

Something like this would work:

```
for name in soup.find_all("span", {"class": "small"}):
    print(name.find("a").get("href"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for extract the value, something like this:

```
import re

input = "adde <a href=\"coedd.com\" > algo</a>";

patt= "href=\"[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+\""

search = re.findall(patt, input, re.I)

print search
```

This return an array with all coincidences.

I hope are useful.

Regards.